# is it good practice to create a global urls object in javascript, for easy reverse routing in templates?

Tags: javascript, ajax, templates, global-variables

I am working on a web project that uses lots of ajax. I am using playframework, and in my html templates, I have access to the playframework reverse router, so I can get urls from the router and not have to worry about what happens if I later decide to change the url structure of the site. However I don't have access tho the reverse router in the external js files, but would often like to leverage the indirection of the reverse router for requests in these files.

I came up with a solution that doesn't force every external ajax function to accept a url parameter, and that was to create a global url object like this:

```
var globalUrls = {
    confirmImageUpload : "@routes.UploadController.confirmResourceUpload()",
    anotherUrl : "@routes.AnotherController.anotherControllerMethod()"
}
```

I then use this object in the external js files to know where to send ajax requests.

Is this ok to do? I don't know if this is bad practice, or if exposing all the urls like that is wise...

I am hoping some experienced individual will interject if this is for some reason dumb...

Answer (score 0):

I think there are other ways of doing it that reduce the amount of globals and make your app a bit more modular, but without seeing how your app is structured it is hard to say.

Maybe you have a class or module that handles your ajax queries, and you can store the urls in that?  For instance, it could have a method "setDefaultAjaxServerAddresses()".  Then it would store those within the module.